# The meaning of "at the proper rates in a cinematograph-film of a bill. "

Tags: meaning

> Before a fortnight was over, Baxter admitted ruefully that M'Leod was better than most firms in the business: We buyers were coy, argumentative, shocked at the price of Holmescroft, inquisitive, and cold by turns, but Mr. M'Leod the seller easily met and surpassed us; and **Mr. Baxter entered every letter, telegram, and consultation at the proper rates in a cinematograph-film of a bill**. At the end of a month he said it looked as though M'Leod, thanks to him, were really going to listen to reason.

This is from "The House Surgeon" by Rudyard Kipling.   
https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2381/2381-h/2381-h.htm#link2H_4_0016

I don't understand the meaning of
Baxter entered every letter, telegram, and consultation at the proper rates in a cinematograph-film of a bill.

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 2):

Lumière Brothers' **Cinematograph** was projected onto a wall in front of an audience, as opposed to Edison's **Kinetoscope** which could be viewed by only one person at a time through an eyepiece.

> Baxter entered every letter, telegram, and consultation at the proper rates in a cinematograph-film of a bill.

The lawyer Baxter added a fee for every correspondence until his bill was (metaphorically) enlarged like a cinematograph-film projected onto a wall.

Comment: It might also refer (metaphorically) just to the length of the bill, with all the individual items adding a frame.

Comment: wetcircuit, Thank you so much for your answer !